# How to identify when an object is empty?

Tags: c#

If I am calling a function:

```
    public User GetUserById(int UserId)
    {
    User someUser = new User();

    //Look up this UserId in the database
     ...
    someUser.Name = dbResult["Name"];

    return someUser;
    }
```

Let's say I pass in a UserId that has no "User information" associated with it.

Suddenly the 'someUser' I'm passing back is instantiated, but empty. What's the best way to check that it's "empty" so I don't try and display data from it?

The caveman in me wants to check if someUser.Name has a length of greater than zero. I know that's awful, so if you know what I'm missing - I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real question is, why would `GetUserById()` return an uninitialized object if the ID is invalid? Wouldn't it be better to throw an exception or - at worst - return `null`?

Comment: +1 for raising an exception.  If you have a userid and it no longer exists it suggests something has gone wrong somewhere

Comment: Can I return null when the return type is User?

Comment: Sure, as long as User is a class and not a struct (and it shouldn't be a struct).

Comment: Yes you can, because User is an object, and any object can be NULL

Comment: I agree that when a function is called GetUserById it should throw an exception if no user is found (depend on what "id" represents). As long as you understand why you should then not thrown an exception if the function were called GetUserByEmail.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, if the id doesn't exist, I'd either return `null`, or (less preferred) I'd throw an `ArgumentException` or `KeyNotFoundException`. That avoids the whole question - you just check against `null`...

Comment: Why do you prefer returning null insted of throwing an exception?

Comment: It avoids the need to catch a "vexing exception" (http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx). I guess it really depends on how likely it is to have IDs that no longer exist; is some (highly transient) systems, this is entirely expected and not exceptional.

Answer (score 4):

**Given your implementation in the question**

Implement an "isEmpty" method that checks *each* instance variable for being in an uninitialized or default state (null for refs, zero for numerics, etc.) The class should know about its own state; it's bad form for external code to pull state out of an instance and then do logic against it. You'll also need to deal with possible ambiguities, such as whether both null and zero length are considered "empty" for string-valued instance variables.

**Alternatives**

1. Return `null` to indicate "no such user".
2. Throw an illegal argument exception to indicate "no such user".
3. Use the *NullObject* pattern and return a subclass of `User` for which `isNull()` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "empty" is very unclear. If there is no record in the database, it's quite logical not to return anything. That is, return `null` if no record exists.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check the result of your database call to see if any record at all was returned? If there are 0 results, you'll know there's no such user, and you won't have to create a User object at all.